# Async execution of statements using threading in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am using below code to execute my code async -
Thread.Join() is used so that once asyncdelete finishes then only start asyncCreateIndex().
This code works fine, but i am sure there willbe better way of doing it like

```
1. I am using two threads, can this below operation not be done using 1 thread or something similar - 

DoSomething(); //Once this finishes start executing below things async
Thread thread = new Thread(() => AsyncDelete(objectFileInfo.FullName));
thread.Start();
thread.Join(); // Wait till asyncdelete() completes
Thread threadIndex = new Thread(() => AsyncCreateIndex(destFileName, false, RepNum, EntityType, Domain, Org, EntityValue, bufferData));
threadIndex.Start();
```

Comment: Yes, not creating Threads explicitly, which has been discouraged for years now. We cannot help you without seeing all the relevant code

Comment: If you kick off code in a new thread, and then sit and wait for it to finish - well, you may as well not have used a new thread to start with. If I send my kids to buy something for me from the shops to save me time, then sit there doing nothing at all waiting for them to return - I may as well have just gone there myself.

Comment: `Tasks` and `async/await` are your friend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make the methods async:

```
async Task AsyncDelete(string name)
{
    var cmd = new SqlCommand
    {
        //Initialize here
    };
    await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
}
```

Then you can just await them:

```
DoSomething(); 
await AsyncDelete(objectFileInfo.FullName);
await AsyncCreateIndex(destFileName, false, RepNum, EntityType, Domain, Org, EntityValue, bufferData);
```

No need for a separate thread.